# How to explain that Harry was able to block a Killing Curse during the Battle of the Seven Potters?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Harry seems to block a Killing Curse with a Stunning Spell during the Battle if the Seven Potters. I could be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure that this is what happened. How to explain this? Could it be that the curse that was blocked was not necessarily a Killing curse but merely another spell that is green? Here is the exact quote from the book: "More Killing Curses flew past Harry's head from the two remaining Death Eaters's wands; they were aiming for Hagrid. Harry responded with further Stunning spells: red and green collided in mid-air in a shower of multi-coloured sparks and Harry thought wildly of fireworks, and the Muggles below who would have no idea what was happening- "

Comment: I would say _exact_ duplicate. Not the rep to VTC though.